# Mostrar e esconder menu não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, toggle

Olá estou tendo um problema quando eu clico no botão toggle menu. Aparentemente o js está funcionando, quando eu vou no inspecionar a classe CSS 'show' é acionada mas não abre o menu que configurei no CSS. Já revisei o código porem não estou encontrando o erro. `

```js
/* abre e fecha o menu quando clicar no ícone: hamburguer e x*/

const nav = document.querySelector('#header .menu-ativo')
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll('nav .toggle')


for (const element of toggle) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    nav.classList.toggle('show')
  })
};
```

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.toggle{
    color: var(--base-color);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-menu::before {
  content: "\e903";

}

.icon-close::before {
  content: "\e900";
}

nav .icon-close {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;

   position: absolute;
   right: 1.5rem;
   top: -1.5rem;
   transition: 0.2s;

}

nav .show.icon-close{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1.5rem;
}

/*************NAVEGATION*************/

nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
  transition: color 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li:hover,
nav ul li:active {
  color: var(--base-color-alt);
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--base-color-alt);

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -0.5rem;

  transition: width 0.2s;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after,
nav ul li a.active::after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav .menu-ativo{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: -20rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

nav .menu-ativo ul{
    display: none;
}

nav.show .menu-ativo {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: var(--header-color);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

nav.show ul{
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="container ">
            
            <a class="logo" href="#inicio"> AMANDA PIOVEZAN <br>
                <span>healing.</span></a>
            <div class="menu-ativo show">
            <ul class=" grid">
             <li class="title"><a href="#inicio">Início</a></li>
             <li class="title"><a href="#terapia">Terapia</a></li>
             <li class="title"><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
             <li class="title"><a href="#depoimentos">Depoimentos</a></li>
             <li class="title"><a href="#duvidas">Dúvidas</a></li>
             <li class="title"><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
         </ul>
            </div>

         <button type="button" class="icon-close toggle"aria-label="fechar"></button>
        
         
         <button type="button" class="icon-menu toggle"aria-label="menu"></button>
         
        </nav>
           
        
    </header>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creio que tenha algo errado no seu CSS já que o JS funciona, de qualquer modo, deixo abaixo um exemplo que foz que funciona para você tomar como base:

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('.menu')

function toggleMenu() {
    nav.classList.toggle('toggle_menu');
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.toggle_menu {
    display: none;
}

.padding {
    padding: 12px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 12px;

    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    background: #333;
}

header>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    left: 0;
    background: teal;
    width: 100%;
}

.container ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container li {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.container li:hover {
    background: rgb(93, 253, 253);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container li a {
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>

        <a class="logo" href="#inicio"> AMANDA PIOVEZAN</a>

        <nav class="container menu toggle_menu padding">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#inicio">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#terapia">Terapia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#depoimentos">Depoimentos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#duvidas">Dúvidas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
        </div>

    </header>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</html>
```